# Codeigniter Model Undefined Index on Array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use Codeigniter to update my value once the user had submitted the form. But unfortunately, there was an error of undefined index for few of the variable which I store in an array.

Below is the Code that I use to pass from Controller to the Model

Controller Code :

```
$prep_data = array(
                'full_name' => $this->input->post('full_name'),
                'nric' => $this->input->post('nric'),
                'dob' => $this->input->post('dob'),
                'mobile_phone' => $this->input->post('mobile_phone'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'address_line_1' => $this->input->post('address_line_1'),
                'address_line_2' => $this->input->post('address_line_2'),
                'postcode' => $this->input->post('postcode'),
                'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
                'current_brand' => $this->input->post('current_brand'),
                'pregnant' => $isPregnant, //Edit by Marcus
                'breastfeeding' => $isBreastfeeding, //Added by Marcus
                'child_full_name' => $this->input->post('child_full_name'),
                'child_dob' => $this->input->post('child_dob'),
                'child_current_brand' => $this->input->post('child_current_brand'),
                'expected_give_birth_date' => $this->input->post('expected_give_birth_date'),
                'image' => '',
                'quantity_purchase' => $this->input->post('quantity_purchase'),
                'foc_amount' => $this->input->post('foc_amount'),
                'marketing_opt' => $this->input->post('marketing_opt'),
                'centre_id' => get_cookie('abbott_centre', TRUE),
                'user_id' => $this->session->id,
                'sampling_day' => $centre_data['sampling_day'],
                'created_at' => $datetime,
                'updated_at' => $datetime
            );
$this->entry_model->update_entry($prep_data);
```

Model Code :

```
   function update_entry($data){
        echo print_r($data);
        if(!empty($data['full_name'])) $this->db->set('full_name', $data['full_name']);
        if(!empty($data['nric'])) $this->db->set('nric', $data['nric']);
        if(!empty($data['dob'])) $this->db->set('dob', $data['dob']);
        if(!empty($data['mobile_phone'])) $this->db->set('mobile_phone', $data['mobile_phone']);
        if(!empty($data['email'])) $this->db->set('email', $data['email']);
        if(!empty($data['address_line_1'])) $this->db->set('address_line_1', $data['address_line_1']);
        if(!empty($data['address_line_2'])) $this->db->set('address_line_2', $data['address_line_2']);
        if(!empty($data['postcode'])) $this->db->set('postcode', $data['postcode']);
        if(!empty($data['state'])) $this->db->set('state', $data['state']);
        if(!empty($data['current_brand'])) $this->db->set('current_brand', $data['current_brand']);
        if(!empty($data['pregnant'])){ //Fix by Marcus
            $this->db->set('pregnant', $data['pregnant']);
        }else {
            $this->db->set('pregnant', 0);
        }
        if(!empty($data['breastfeeding'])){ //Fix by Marcus
            $this->db->set('breastfeeding', $data['breastfeeding']);
        }
        else {
            $this->db->set('breastfeeding', 0);
        }
        if(!empty($data['expected_give_birth_date'])) $this->db->set('expected_give_birth_date', $data['expected_give_birth_date']);//Fix by Marcus
        if(!empty($data['child_full_name'])) $this->db->set('child_full_name', $data['child_full_name']);
        if(!empty($data['child_dob'])) $this->db->set('child_dob', $data['child_dob']);
        if(!empty($data['child_current_brand'])) $this->db->set('child_current_brand', $data['child_current_brand']);
        if(!empty($data['image'])) $this->db->set('image', $data['image']);
        if(isset($data['quantity_purchase'])) $this->db->set('quantity_purchase', $data['quantity_purchase']);
        if(isset($data['foc_amount'])) $this->db->set('foc_amount', $data['foc_amount']);
        if(!empty($data['marketing_opt'])) $this->db->set('marketing_opt', $data['marketing_opt']);
        if(!empty($data['centre_id'])) $this->db->set('centre_id', $data['centre_id']);
        if(!empty($data['user_id'])) $this->db->set('user_id', $data['user_id']);
        if(!empty($data['created_at'])) $this->db->set('created_at', $data['created_at']);
        if(!empty($data['updated_at'])) $this->db->set('updated_at', $data['updated_at']);

        $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
        $this->db->update('entry');
    }
```

Other $data[] value had no problem but only the 'pregnant' and 'breastfeeding' had the error on Undefined Index. I did try to print_r to show the $data value and all are seem to be alright.

Below are the output :

```
Array ( [full_name] => e2e [nric] => 123 [dob] => 2019-07-09 [mobile_phone] => 1231231231 [email] => [address_line_1] => [address_line_2] => [postcode] => [state] => [current_brand] => [pregnant] => 0 [breastfeeding] => 1 [child_full_name] => [child_dob] => 0000-00-00 [child_current_brand] => [expected_give_birth_date] => 2019-07-09 [image] => [quantity_purchase] => 123123 [foc_amount] => 123 [sampling_day] => [updated_at] => 2019-07-10 19:27:43 [id] => 8 ) 1Array ( [image] => 8_20190710_192743.jpg [id] => 8 ) 1
```

What will be the caused for this 'pregnant' and 'breastfeeding' array? As it keeps getting NULL as a return.

Thanks

Comment: try this in controller 'breastfeeding' => $isBreastfeeding ? $isBreastfeeding : '', and 'pregnant' => $isPregnant ? $isPregnant, : '',

Comment: `$isPregnant` and `$isBreastfeeding` where you defined these two variables? error is not related to your model, as its already defined

Comment: @bobibobi sorry your method not working Message: syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: @devpro Here $isPregnant = 0;
   $isBreastfeeding = 0;
   if($this->input->post('pregnant') == 1){
    $isBreastfeeding = 0;
    $isPregnant = 1; //Is breastfeeding selected    
   }
   if($this->input->post('breastfeeding') == 1){
    $isPregnant = 0;
    $isBreastfeeding = 1; //Is breastfeeding selected
   }

Comment: so if `$this->input->post('pregnant')` not set?

Comment: @devpro what do you mean?

Comment: my mistake try this :  'breastfeeding' => isset($isBreastfeeding) ? $isBreastfeeding : "", and 'pregnant' => isset($isPregnant) ? $isPregnant, : "",

Comment: @bobibobi same also undefined index

Comment: they way is it with this code print_r($data['breastfeeding']) in model and let us know the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check either index set or not like

```
$isPregnant = 0; 
$isBreastfeeding = 0; 
if(isset($_POST['pregnant']) && $_POST['pregnant'] == 1)
{ 
    $isBreastfeeding = 0; 
    $isPregnant = 1; //Is breastfeeding selected    
} 

if(isset($_POST['breastfeeding']) && $_POST['breastfeeding'] == 1)
{ 
    $isPregnant = 0; 
    $isBreastfeeding = 1; //Is breastfeeding selected 
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: @MarcusTan: then you can use `$_POST`